# TableView: is it possible to Delete existing rows and insert new rows without reloading tableview or section?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a list of categories(CollectionView in section header), I am trying to display data in the section rows without reloading section header. With the following code ,

- if rows(*already loaded cells*) = post.count(*new posts to be displayed*) it works
- if rows > post.count it works
- **BUT if rows < post.count , it gives error ,
  'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (4 inserted, 2 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'**

  ````
         var newIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
         var rows = 0
         rows = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 1)
         self.tableView.beginUpdates()
         if rows > posts.count {
             print("rows is greater")
             for row in 0...rows {
                 if rows <= posts.count {
                     break
                 }else{
                     tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(item: row, section: 1)], with: .none)
                     rows -= 1
                 }
             }
         } else if posts.count > rows {
             print("post is greater")
             for post in 0...posts.count{
                 if post < rows {
                     newIndexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: post, section: 1))
                 }
             }
             self.tableView.insertRows(at: newIndexPaths, with: .none)
         } else {
      for row in 0...posts.count - 1 {
                 newIndexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: row, section: 1))
                 break
             }   
         }
         self.tableView.reloadRows(at: newIndexPaths, with: .none)
         self.tableView.endUpdates() ```
  ````

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, but you have to keep the data source array and the table view in sync.

If `posts` represents the data source array of section 1 you can insert a row

```
let insertionIndex = 0
posts.insert(newItem, at: insertionIndex)
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: insertionIndex, section: 1)], with: .automatic)
```

or delete a row

```
let indexToDelete = 5
posts.remove(at: indexToDelete)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: indexToDelete, section: 1)], with: .fade)
```

In both cases `cellForRowAt` is **not** being called.

It's important that you **first** `insert`/`remove` the item into/from the data source and then call `insert/deleteRows`

---

The same applies to multiple rows. For example you can delete all items in section 1 with

```
let indexPaths : [IndexPath] = posts.indices.map{[1, $0]}
posts.removeAll()
tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade).
```

In all my examples `begin-/endUpdates` is not needed because it's a single insert/delete operation.